# How to automate data extraction from Cassandra in csv format once in a day

Tags: spring-boot, groovy, cassandra, scripting, spring-data-cassandra

Can you please suggest me the approach to extract data from the Cassandra once in a day in CSV format.

Should I go for java application or any scripting language?

Comment: Please extend your post with more details on what you want to achieve - do you need to dump all data, or only for particular time/day, etc. If the later, then what table structure you have, etc.

Comment: My requirement is to fetch all the column-family data from a keyspace in csv   format and store it in a directory .

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `COPY TO` command in `cqlsh`, like this:

```
COPY keyspace.table (list_of_columns_if_only_some_required) 
   TO 'filename.csv' WITH HEADER = TRUE ;
```

You can put this command into file, and then execute it with `cqlsh -f commands.cql`.  But be aware that if you table is big, than it may make performance of your cluster worse, as it will need to grab & transfer all data.

Options of `COPY` command are described at [official documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlshCopy.html).